# Successor commands to cy.window not running/working

Tags: cypress

We use d3 components for visualization and moving them around is tricky since they are svg elements and not html elements (for the most part). Thanks to [this answer](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3441) and [another link](https://gist.github.com/xphong/da749756386dae4adc23fa7c40cfbf19). Following both links I was able to get the nodes moving as expected. This is what worked for me:

```
const options = { log: false, force: true };

Cypress.Commands.add("moveNode", (nodeIdToBeMoved, targetNodeId) => {
  cy.window().then(options, (win) => {
    cy.getByDataAutomationId(`hierarchy_node_${nodeIdToBeMoved}`)
      .trigger("mousedown", {
        view: win,
        which: 1,
        ...options,
      })
      .wait(1000, options)
      .trigger("mousemove", {
        view: win,
        which: 1,
        ...options,
      })
      .get(
        `g[aut-id="hierarchy_node_${targetNodeId}"] .drop-rect.bottom`
      )
      .trigger("mouseover", {
        view: win,
        which: 1,
        ...options
      })
      .trigger("mouseup", {
        view: win,
        which: 1,
        ...options
      });
  });
});
```

Running any command right after the moveNode command chained using . operator (and YES both the commands are mentioned in the index.d.ts file) doesn't work. Would like to mention that moveNode works perfectly fine but the successor commands don't work. If I switch the order other way around then everything works but unfortunately I need to make assertions only after move has happened.

The test looks like the following:

```
    cy
                .clickNode(subChild)
                .getActiveFromInNodeEditor()
                .then((activeFromCtrl) => {
                    let valueBeforeMove = activeFromCtrl.val();
                    cy
                        .moveNode(subChildPos1_OfSubChild1GlobalId, rootPositionGlobalId)
                        .clickNode(parent) // this doesn't work. Any interaction event such as click etc. doesn't work hence the click is still left on the child which was done before moveNode command
                        .getActiveFromInNodeEditor()
                        .should('have.value', valueBeforeMove)
                })

Cypress.Commands.add("clickNode", (id) => {
  cy
  .get(`[aut-id=hierarchy_node_${id}]`)
  .click({
    force: true,
    ...options,
  })
  .wait(100);
});
```

Running the test using cypress runner, I can see the command was executed but it does nothing. Even hovering over it the Before and After states are exactly the same. The test just passes silently without any error  . Everything works when trying to perform same operations manually.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please post code as text not picture. Also, what are the "successor commands"? Please post the test as well as the custom command.

Comment: Oh the next command can be literally anything, as simple as clicking an element '''cy.click('#id')''' and it just doesn't work. Anything followed after this command doesn't work unless I am calling this same command (with different or same params)

Comment: `cy.click('#id')` is a syntax error, which I guess is a good reason to show what you are trying.

Comment: updated the question with exact test thanks!

Comment: so the application code just added some animation after node movement and that did not let the next command work. I assumed from https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Animations that cypress waits for animations automatically but turns out it doesn't. Anyways explicit sleep after the moveNode fixed the problem.